# How can I transfer each value in a list into an excel sheet using a for loop?

Tags: python, excel, for-loop, openpyxl, data-processing

I am trying to take each value in my list and transfer it into an excel sheet. I have code in the excel sheet that will import additional information based on this value. I then want to be able to save and copy the sheet. Then I want to insert the next value in my list and save and copy the sheet etc. Therefore, the end result will be a number of saved documents equivalent to the amount of values in my list. I currently am only getting one saved/copied sheet with the last value of my list in it. Here is my code:

```
filename = fr'/home/elinor/Documents/data.xlsx'
wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename)
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]
filename1 = fr'/home/elinor/Documents/Report.xlsx'
wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename1)
ws2 = wb2.worksheets[0]
mr = ws1.max_row
mc = ws1.max_column

for i in range (2, mr + 1):
    rowSelected = []
    for j in range (1, 1 + 1, 1):
        c = ws1.cell(row=i, column=j)
        rowSelected.append(c.value)
        print(rowSelected)
    for x in rowSelected:
        ws2['B4'] = x
        wb2.save(filename1)
        shutil.copyfile(filename1, fr'/home/elinor/Documents/Report_Folder')
```

Comment: Looks like you are always saving to the same file (filename1)

Comment: I am trying to save and copy the file each time it goes through the for loop.

Comment: Yes, you are saving it multiple times, but you always use the same filename (/home/elinor/Documents/Report.xlsx), so you are just overwriting the file with the new value, which is why the single output file contains the last value of your list.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations on how to automate giving each file its own name when it is saved?

Comment: I was able to rename and copy each file individually with this code:        if os.path.exists('Report.xlsx'):
            a=str(x)
            shutil.copyfile(filename1, fr'/home/elinor/Documents/Report_Folder/'+a)

Comment: Now I just have multiple saved files with the same value in all of them. It only gives me the last value in the list.

Comment: If you can post an example of the data you have in the excel sheet I can try to debug it locally.

Comment: And update the code in your question as well with whatever you've added